# RADAR image for dBZ values

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, python-imaging-library

I need to perform a home study with data from a weather radar located in Brazil, but at the moment I only have the .png image of the hail event.

I need to convert the image into a datum using the legend to make the values, the stronger the higher the reflectivity (dBZ datum).

The data and legend are from the website: https://www.redemet.aer.mil.br/

Legend:

[image]

Image:

[image]

I'm using the following script to convert to gray and then register values ​​below a threshold that I think, but this methodology is not good.

```
#load Packages
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open Image with PIL
img = Image.open('./BRSG_20230417_135600_0_source.png')

# other data https://estatico-redemet.decea.mil.br/radar/2023/05/27/sg/maxcappi/maps/2023-05-27--10:56:27.png

# Convert image to grayscale
img_cinza = img.convert('L')

# Convert the image to a NumPy array
arr = np.array(img_cinza)

# Santiago Radar specifications
# extent = [-59.189733162586094, -50.844752805434396, -32.814210356963194, -25.573430009385245]
latt = np.arange(-32.814210356963194, -25.573430009385245, 0.018101950868944873)
lonn = np.arange(-59.189733162586094, -50.844752805434396, 0.020862450892879244)
#lonn = lonn - 360
latt = latt[::-1]

Xi, Yi = np.meshgrid(lonn,latt)

# creating an array for by latitude, longitude and data
dd = np.zeros([3,latt.shape[0],lonn.shape[0]])
# dd = np.zeros([3,400,400])

dd[0,:,:] = arr[:,:]
dd[1,:,:] = Yi[:,:]
dd[2,:,:] = Xi[:,:]

dd[0,:,:][dd[0,:,:]==0] = np.nan

# Here I only filter data below 80 (should be where dBZ reflectivity is highest = thunderstorm)
dd[0,:,:][dd[0,:,:] >= 80] = np.nan


# plot
plt.imshow(dd[0,:,:])

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy 
import numpy as np
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import cartopy
# plt.imshow(, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.contourf(dd[2,:,:], dd[1,:,:], dd[0,:,:], extent = [-59, -45, -35, -22.0], transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())    

# Create a feature for States/Admin 1 regions at 1:50m from Natural Earth
states_provinces = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(
    category='cultural',
    name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines',
    scale='50m',
    facecolor='none')
    
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(states_provinces, edgecolor='gray')

ax.coastlines(resolution='10m', color='black', linewidth=0.8)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5)
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), color='gray', alpha=1.0, linestyle='--', linewidth=0.25, xlocs=np.arange(-180, 180, 5), ylocs=np.arange(-90, 90, 5), draw_labels=True)
gl.top_labels = False
gl.right_labels = False
```

Thanks

Comment: Explicitly, what are you expecting as a result exactly? You say *"a datum"* but what is that? A number? A word?

Comment: And does the legend change with each download or is it fixed?